# Deriving dipolar coupling in spherical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, dipole

I am trying to get to the [well-known expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction) of the tensorial coupling between two dipolar quantities, written as an interaction between two centers $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}'$ using their distance $d=|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|$ and the unit vector $\vec{e}_d$ connecting them as

$$
T(\vec{r},\vec{r}') = \frac{1}{d^3}(3-\vec{e}_d \otimes \vec{e}_d)
$$

My understanding is that this tensor is obtained by taking the double derivative of the scalar Coulomb potential as

$$
T(\vec{r},\vec{r}') =\nabla_{\vec{r}} \nabla_{\vec{r}'}\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} 
$$

If I treat the distance between the two centers in Cartesian coordinates I can take this derivative with relative simplicity by treating components separately, such as

$$
\partial_{r_i}\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} =\frac{r_a-r'_a}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|^3}
$$

I can obtain an expression for each $T_{ij}$ tensor component this way, and I can then show that this tensor is equivalent to the one expressed using only the distances between the two points (in the beginning).

However, what I would want to do is to evaluate the derivatives in spherical coordinates in hopes of getting the final expression directly, but I am having a hard time understanding how to take the derivatives. For example, if I try to take the derivative with respect to the first vector (and I only have radial components) I'm getting

$$
\nabla_{\vec{r}} \frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} \vec{e}_{r} = \frac{(\vec{r}'-\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|^3} \vec{e}_{r} \, ,
$$

which seems to be on the right track, but the second derivative will give me

$$
\nabla_{\vec{r}'} \frac{(\vec{r}'-\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|^3} \vec{e}_{r}  = \frac{\partial}{\partial r'}\frac{(\vec{r}'-\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|^3} \vec{e}_{r}\vec{e}_{r'} = \frac{-2}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|^3} ( \vec{e}_{r} \cdot\vec{e}_{r'}) \, ,
$$

which is obviously not the correct expression.

Where did I go wrong?